# HoloEverywhere error in implementation with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

After importing `Sherlock` successfully, I am implementing `HoloEverywhere`.

The only problems i'm facing are as shown in the image below, `android.support.v4.app` compilation error and `pom.xml` error too.

[image]
These errors are showing up even after importing the library (Sherlock) in Properties>Android and Properties>Java Build Path.

Any hint regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Delete Android support liabary in your apps libs folder.

Comment: But there is no "libs" folder in HoloEverywhere Library. I haven't created a new project yet for my app i'm just initializing the implementation

Comment: Make sure that abs is added to holoeverywheres dependencies.